# Como extrair o atributo de dentro do A HREF com o Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Galera eu pesquisei muito e não consegui solucionar esse problema. É o seguinte, eu consigo extrair as informações de texto, por exemplo:

```
<span class="style13">texto para extrair</span>
```

Mas o que quer queria é extrair o link do A HREF, exemplo:

```
<a href="extrair o link" target="_blank">texto</a>
```

Com esse código eu pego muita informação:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  doc : IHTMLDocument3;
  elements : IHTMLElementCollection;
  element : IHTMLElement;
  i : integer;
begin
    doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument3;

    elements := doc.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for i := 0 to elements.length - 1 do begin
        element := elements.item(i, 0) as IHTMLElement;
        Memo1.Lines.Add(element.innerHTML);
    end;
end;
```

Gostaria de obter uma resposta mais específica, se possível apenas extrair o link mesmo.

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por um lado pode usar o Pos, LeftSTR e o RightSTR para fazer cortes na string e extrair a info que pretende.

Por outro, mais versatil, pode usar as Expressoes Regulares para extrair o que precisa.
Eu fiz uma pequena funçao para facilitar isso

```
function Webpage_ReadValue(AText:string;AStart,AEnd:string):string;
var
  MatchVar:TRegEx;
  MatchInfo:TMatch;
  value:Variant;
  RegExpress:string;
begin
  result:='';
  RegExpress:='(?i)'+AStart+'[\s\S]+?'+AEnd;
  if RegExpress<>'' then
  begin
    try
      MatchVar:=TRegEx.Create(RegExpress);
      MatchInfo:=MatchVar.Match(AText);
      if MatchInfo.Value<>null then
        result:=MatchInfo.Value;
    finally

    end;
  end;
end;
```

Atenção que no seu caso pode ser preciso alteraçoes, nomeadamente fazer o replace do AStart e do AEnd por '' no fim...

Comment: É não teve jeito de extrair, se existe como eu não sei fazer haha Obrigado pela ajuda, consegui chegar onde queria usando sua ideia, olhe em baixo como fiz.

Comment: Ok ;) Se resolveu está optimo

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, fiz dessa forma:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  doc : IHTMLDocument3;
  elements : IHTMLElementCollection;
  element : IHTMLElement;
  str : string;
  i : integer;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument3;

  elements := doc.getElementsByTagName(Edit3.Text);

  for i := 0 to elements.length - 1 do begin

    element := (elements.item(i, 0)) as IHTMLElement;

    str := element.innerhtml;
    str := Copy(str, Pos('href', str)+6, Length(str));

    if str.Contains('http') then begin

      str := Copy(str, 0, Pos('>', str)-2);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(str);

    end;

  end;
end;
```